# Transform Array in Snowflake Table Using Data From Different Table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have these two tables:

```
Table_A
| ID |             EMP            |
|----|----------------------------|
| 1  | [[1,200], [4,100], [5,60]] |
| 2  | [[1,200], [2,90], [3,45]]  |
| 3  | [[2,250], [4,200], [5,100]]|

Table_B
| BUILD_ID |    NAME    |
|----------|------------|
| 1        |    DT_A    |
| 2        |    DT_B    |  
| 3        |    DT_C    |
| 4        |    DT_D    |
| 5        |    DT_E    |
```

I want to add a column to Table_A that is mapped from Table_B so that Table_A looks like this:

```
| ID |             EMP            |                   MAP                  |
|----|----------------------------|----------------------------------------|
| 1  | [[1,200], [4,100], [5,60]] | [[DT_A, 200], [DT_D, 100], [DT_E, 60]] |
| 2  | [[1,250]                   | [[DT_A, 250]]                          |
| 3  | [[2,250], [4,200], [5,100]]| [[DT_B, 250], [DT_D, 200], [DT_E, 100]]|
```

What is the query?

Comment: You have tags for both MySQL and Snowflake. Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flatten, array_construct, and array_agg to do this:

```
create or replace table TABLE_A(ID int, EMP array);
insert into TABLE_A select 1, parse_json('[[1,200], [4,100], [5,60]]');
insert into TABLE_A select 2, parse_json('[[1,200], [2,90], [3,45]]');
insert into TABLE_A select 3, parse_json('[[2,250], [4,200], [5,100]]');

create or replace table TABLE_B(BUILD_ID int, NAME string);
insert into TABLE_B (BUILD_ID, NAME) values
(1,'DT_A'),
(2,'DT_B'),
(3,'DT_C'),
(4,'DT_D'),
(5,'DT_E');

with F1 as
(
select ID, VALUE[0] as ID_MAP, VALUE[1] as EMP from TABLE_A, table(flatten(EMP))
), JOINED as
(
select ID, ID_MAP, EMP, BUILD_ID, NAME from F1
    inner join TABLE_B B
        on F1.ID_MAP = B.BUILD_ID
)
select   ID
        ,array_agg(array_construct(BUILD_ID, EMP)) within group (order by NAME) EMP
        ,array_agg(array_construct(NAME, EMP)) within group (order by NAME) MAP
from joined
group by ID
order by ID
;
```

If you want to change the order of the arrays, you can change the sort order of `within group order by (NAME)` to order by something else (provided it's in the array manipulations such as BUILD_ID - if the column is not in the array manipulations the sort will not be stable).

Output:

| ID | EMP | MAP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [ [ 1, 200 ], [ 4, 100 ], [ 5, 60 ] ] | [ [ "DT_A", 200 ], [ "DT_D", 100 ], [ "DT_E", 60 ] ] |
| 2 | [ [ 1, 200 ], [ 2, 90 ], [ 3, 45 ] ] | [ [ "DT_A", 200 ], [ "DT_B", 90 ], [ "DT_C", 45 ] ] |
| 3 | [ [ 2, 250 ], [ 4, 200 ], [ 5, 100 ] ] | [ [ "DT_B", 250 ], [ "DT_D", 200 ], [ "DT_E", 100 ] ] |

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
SELECT 
    CTE.ID
  , CTE.EMP  
  , ARRAY_AGG(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(TABLE_B.NAME,CTE.LETS_KEEP )) NEW_PAYLOAD 
FROM 
    (SELECT GG.ID,G.VALUE[0] LETS_REPLACE, G.VALUE[1] LETS_KEEP,GG.EMP 
        FROM TABLE_A GG,LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT=>EMP)G) CTE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    TABLE_B ON TABLE_B.BUILD_ID = LETS_REPLACE
GROUP BY 
     1,2


courtesy of greg :
create or replace table TABLE_A(ID int, EMP array);
insert into TABLE_A select 1, parse_json('[[1,200], [4,100], [5,60]]');
insert into TABLE_A select 2, parse_json('[[1,200], [2,90], [3,45]]');
insert into TABLE_A select 3, parse_json('[[2,250], [4,200], [5,100]]');

create or replace table TABLE_B(BUILD_ID int, NAME string);
insert into TABLE_B (BUILD_ID, NAME) values
(1,'DT_A'),
(2,'DT_B'),
(3,'DT_C'),
(4,'DT_D'),
(5,'DT_E');
```